# Conectar Mysql Workbench a mysql en ubuntu server 16.04 maquina virtual

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

Buenas tardes, tengo un sistema en **ubuntu server 16.04.02 LTS** con una base de datos **Mysql**, todo en *maquina virtual VMware fusion* y *conexion NAT* en cual puedo ver la aplicacion y acceder mediante phpmyadmin. Pero quiero ver la base de datos con *MysqlWorkbench* trato de conectar y manda el error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on (61).

Habilite en la base **Mysql** un nuevo usuario con privilegios y con la `ip` de donde quiero conectar y otra de `%`, pero aun asi no puedo.

Que solucion pueden sugerirme

Comment: puede que no habilitastes la conexion de mysql  modifica el my.ini la siguiente linea **bind-address = 0.0.0.0** y reinicia

Comment: Conexion Puente en tu configuración de la maquina virtual

Comment: agregue el bind-address pero al reiniciar servicios manda error.